# Using $_GET instead of $_SESSION

Tags: php

**How do you set a $GET variable?**

Hi i have done this before, but my method is a bit hit and miss so i was wondering what is the correct way to do this.

My url is:
Franchise-Details.php?Franchise=Enfield/status=Driver

And i want to set the Franchise name and staff status as a variable as i will be using them continuously throughout my webpage.

This is what i have done:

```
   $admin_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['status']); 

   $fr_Area = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['Franchise']);
```

But it does not work. No error messages, just shows nothing if i try to apply it, for example echo $fr_area;. If i change the get to session it works. But i want to use get.

I have also tried:

```
   if (isset($_GET['status'])){
   $admin_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['status']); 
   }

    if (isset($_GET['Franchise'])){
    $admin_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['Franchise']); 
    }
```

How can i improve this

Comment: rather than / you need & so ` Franchise-Details.php?Franchise=Enfield&status=Driver` $_GET['status'] will give you Driver

Comment: @Matt create! that got one working, ill work on the other. thank you

Comment: @Monrow what's the other issue?